# UITabBarController not showing all view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

My UITabBarcontroller has two view controllers
-Favorites
-Keypad

I add these two controllers in an array in the order Favorites,Keypad,nil.

When the app is launched only the Favorites tab appears in the tabbar, I have to click the second tab for the "Keypad" (Title of the viewController) text to appear on the tabbar.

How do I make the tabbar have the title of both the view controllers at startup itself?

Answer (score 0):

show us your tabbarcontroller init method.  It should be straight forward -

-create 1 tabbarcontroller

-create 2 tabbaritems

-create 2 nav controller

-assign tabbaritems to nav controllers, using navcontroller.tabBarItem property

-use tabbarcontroller setViewControllers:animated: function to add nav controllers to tabbar, then add tabbar controller to window.

Comment: I found the problem, I was declaring the title of one the second viewcontroller in its ViewDidLoad method. That is why the title only showed when I tapped on the second tabbar. Now that I have declared the title of the view in the appdelegate itself it shows the title without tapping on it

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `ViewController` where you load the `tabController`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // creating the tabController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myViewController, nil];

    myViewController.title = @"Title";

    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
    [controllers release];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

Comment: @user757343: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** Please, indent every line of code by **4 spaces**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
-(id)setup
{
    UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"xxxx" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xxx.png"] tag:0];
    self.tabBarItem = item;
    [item release];
    return self;
}



-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
```